# Why can't I define these macro names?

Tags: c++

If I make a define at the command like `-Dfirst` and `-Dsecond` I get a bunch of errors:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/ostream:38:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/ios:40:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/bits/char_traits.h:39:
In file included from /usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:
/usr/local/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/../../../../include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_pair.h:101:11: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
      _T1 first;                 /// @c first is a copy of the first object
      ~~~ ^
<command line>:1:15: note: expanded from here
#define first 1
              ^
...
              ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

But if I use capital `FIRST` and `SECOND` it's fine.

Comment: Basically, the compiler tells you the reason. Pair contains a variable with name first. You would replace the variable with a `1`.

Comment: *A translation unit that includes a standard library header shall not `#define` or `#undef` names declared in
any standard library header.*

Answer (score 7):

If you define first and second before including anything, that includes `std::pair` inside `<algorithm>`, it will screw your code, because the variables inside `std::pair` are called `first` and `second`, and your macro is defined to that, so it expands the names to the expression they are defined to, making your code malformed.

Basically, its the same as doing

```
#define A 1

class A{
};
```

This will also not compile, because A gets converted to 1, and `1` is not valid class name

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, first and second are used all over the STL, so by defining them to nothing you've rendered it unparseable